# How to fix before pseudoclass at parent

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, fixed

My intent is set fixed the position of the :before pseudoclass, like a header, so the "JSON language" text will reamain fixed, regardless the position of scrollbar.

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.code {
  --alpha: #00000011;
    background: var(--alpha);
    overflow-x: auto;
    padding: 1.2rem;
}

.code:before {
    content: attr(plang) " language";

    display: block;
    background: var(--alpha);
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<pre class="code" plang="JSON">
{
    "extension": "json",
    "css_path": "styles/syntax/json",
    "rules": [
        {
            "regex": "\"(\\\\.|[^\"])+\"(?=\\s*:)",
            "type": "key"
        },
        {
            "regex": "(null|true|false|-?\\d+\\.?\\d*|\"(\\\\.|[^\"])+\")(?=\\s*[,}\\]])",
            REALLY LONG TEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEXT
            "type": "value"
        }
    ]
}
</pre>
```

Comment: add `position: sticky` and `top: 0` to `.code:before {}`. also, add  `display: table` to `.code {}`

Comment: @s.kuznetsov this does not work, cause of display table, .code does not have max-width size, and if i remove it, still does nothing

Comment: I just checked. It works for me.